# javax.servlet.ServletException the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2, mojarra

I've the below form which uploads a file via `<h:inputFile>` and `<f:ajax>`.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{bean.file}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{bean.upload}">
        <f:ajax execute="file" render="file" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

When I submit it, I get a JavaScript alert with the below error information:

> serverError: class javax.servlet.ServletException the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

Is there any solution for this problem? I'm using Mojarra 2.2.11.

Comment: Are you nesting forms?

Comment: I have only one form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced it. It is a bug in Mojarra, introduced in 2.2.9 as side effect of the fix for [issue 3129](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3129). Your problem is already reported as [issue 3765](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3765). Basically: uploading files with ajax is broken since Mojarra 2.2.9 and there are no workarounds (at least not without hacking in the code).

For now, you need to downgrade to Mojarra 2.2.8 until they release the version with the fix.

Comment: Yes downgrading Mojarra seems to work. One additional question: I click Browse button and I select file to upload. Then I click Upload button and when the file is uploaded I see label `No file selected`. Maybe the file is transferred to the managed bean? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: That will indeed happen if you re-render the file input. It will then be like as if it is reinitialized to default. Change `<f:ajax render>` if you don't want this.